# How do I set a static file as root using salvo?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have the following code...

```
use salvo_extra::serve::*;
use salvo::prelude::*;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let router = Router::new()
        .push(
            Router::new()
                .path("static")
                .get(StaticFile::new("static/index.html")),
        );
    Server::new(router).bind(([0, 0, 0, 0], 7878)).await;
}
```

Works great when I go to `http://localhost:7878/static` I see the site. However, what I really want is for it to be at `http://loclalhost:7878` so I try this...

```
let router = Router::new()
        .push(
            Router::new()
                .path("")
                .get(StaticFile::new("static/index.html")),
        );
```

I also tried `"/"` but I get a 404. How do I host the static file at the root using salvo?

Comment: Have you tried `.path("/")`? If that's what you meant by, "I also tried `"/"` but I get a 404", it might help to share where you're getting `Router` and `Server` from so people can run the code themselves.

Comment: Added that is why I had salvo in the title, sorry new to this. Anyway yes I have tried the path the way you have described

Answer (score 0):

I had to get rid of the `path` entirely this worked...

```
let router = Router::new()
        .push(
            Router::new().get(StaticFile::new("static/index.html"))
        ).push(
        Router::new().path("test").get(StaticFile::new("static/test.html"))
        );
```